# Need to show full number, but does not work

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code,

```
 document.getElementById("result37").value = result37.toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 8 });
```

I am trying to get it to show it like this   12345678.12, but cannot get it to show .12

Comment: What type of field is `#result37`?

Comment: You should share what you get from document.getElementById("result37").value

Comment: Here is the full code

Comment: [It's showing the fractions fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/3tkcp8dj/) @Hendrik. You'll need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `minimumFractionDigits` option. You can also use the `maximumFractionDigits` option for the maximum digit number. This is the code for a minimum of 3 fraction digits:

```
let number = 12345678.12;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 3 })); // 12,345,678.120
```

Comment: function multiply37() {
   var num73 = document.getElementById("firstNum18").value;
            document.getElementById("secondNum18").value = 540;
            var num74 = document.getElementById("secondNum18").value;
            var result37 = num73 * num74;
            document.getElementById("result37").value = result37.toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 8 });
   
            document.getElementById("result37").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("result37").style.fontWeight = "900";
        }
    </script>

Comment: This is my code